# I can't figure out the reason for error in Heroku log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, omniauth, heroku-postgres, omniauth-twitter

My Heroku Logs are pictured below.  I cannot figure out what is going wrong.  Please help :(

[Heroku Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zAqL.png)

Comment: can you post more of the logs and explain exactly what it is that is going wrong, are you getting the application error page?  There is no error that I can see in the image you posted. Has the app ever run on heroku?

Comment: It will not load the html.  I get the "We're sorry, something went wrong" in the browser.   I figured out that if I remove the all of the bootstrap navbar html from application.html.erb, it displays simple html.  I'm assuming that this means it is having trouble loading the bootstrap elements? I have the bootstrap-sass gem in the gemfile??

Comment: or a variable inside the navbar maybe, Has it ever run on heroku?

Comment: I just pushed to heroku last night.  Have been fighting bugs all day.

Comment: You have run heroku rake db:migrate and everything else needed to set it up though?

Comment: any idea why that /favicon.ico GET request would be the last thing it runs?  I don't even know what favicon.ico is lol

Comment: Yes, I ran all that.  If I take out the navbar, it will continue through to the =%yield and display the simple html in the root_path

Comment: find favicon.ico and paste it in your public folder.  it is that tiny little icon that appears next to website titles.

Comment: @MichaelBlank  hope that helps.

Comment: @MichaelBlank please post your logs instead of a link to them. This will avoid link rot on S.O. Also, please include the error in your question to make it easier for people to answer or find a question similar to their's. Welcome to Stack Overflow!